# Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined at test.html:11

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm completing my cs50 final project so am coding in the cs50 ide. I am trying to create a graph using chart.js so am using the test code they provide to try and get it to work on my website. However I am getting the error written in the title when I'm on my server. I have tried putting the JavaScript code in a separate file but that does not work either. Any ideas  as to what i am doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script scr="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <title> Chart</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],}]
                }});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your chart JS script inclusion.
You have done `scr` and not `src`.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```